# something like dropdown in a android app?

Tags: android

I'm searching for a widget in a android app where the user can select a item from a specific list. it's only possible to select one and the list is defined by the app.

it's like a dropdown. I can't use a simple listView because I need at least 4 of there controls on one page. so what is a good solution?

Comment: I'm not really sure what's the problem but Spinner can't do the trick? http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you are looking for something like [Spinners](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

Answer (score 3):

[Spinners](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Spinner` in android for dropdown.or you can use `AlertDialog` as like that of drodown.For using spinner read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html).For using `AlertDialog` read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)